# Expo npm packages vulnerabilities not fixable

Tags: react-native, npm, package, expo, npm-vulnerabilities

I've been trying to fix the vulnerabilities of a few packages in my React Native Expo project for a few hours now , but nothing seems to work.

I've tried `npm update`, `npm audit fix --force`, `npm update dep@latest`, changing the version of dep with vulnerabilities to the version and running `npm i`, removing package-lock, etc. But nothing works. My `npm audit report` looks like this:

```
# npm audit report

qs  6.7.0 - 6.7.2
Severity: high
qs vulnerable to Prototype Pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hrpp-h998-j3pp
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@44.0.6, which is a breaking change
node_modules/qs
  body-parser  1.19.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of qs
  node_modules/body-parser
    @expo/dev-server  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of body-parser
    node_modules/@expo/dev-server
      @expo/cli  >=0.1.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/dev-server
      node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli
        expo  >=45.0.0-beta.1
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/cli
        node_modules/expo

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

After I run `npm audit fix --force` again it looks like this:

```
# npm audit report

node-fetch  <=2.6.6
Severity: high
The `size` option isn't honored after following a redirect in node-fetch - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w7rc-rwvf-8q5r
node-fetch is vulnerable to Exposure of Sensitive Information to an Unauthorized Actor - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r683-j2x4-v87g
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@47.0.8, which is a breaking change
node_modules/isomorphic-fetch/node_modules/node-fetch
  isomorphic-fetch  2.0.0 - 2.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
  node_modules/isomorphic-fetch
    fbjs  0.7.0 - 1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of isomorphic-fetch
    node_modules/fbemitter/node_modules/fbjs
      fbemitter  2.0.3 - 3.0.0-alpha.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
      node_modules/fbemitter
        expo  14.0.0 - 44.0.6
        Depends on vulnerable versions of fbemitter
        node_modules/expo

5 vulnerabilities (4 low, 1 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

Which seems weird to me because it shows different dependencies. And when I run it again it shows the first dependencies again.

Answer (score 0):

Hello im having the same issue the only way i fixed it was by forcing update of the the qs in the node_modulus .So i updated it with another library https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions , but its not recommended to do it this way, if you found another way plz tell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).